# jetty websockets only server - no http server - remove the 404 error

Tags: java, jetty, http-status-code-404, websocket, embedded-jetty

I've implemented a small web-sockets server using jetty, embedded in a larger java application. The server is running on 8081 port, and everything works ok(tested with a small client , in google chrome). However if I try to access the http://localhost:8081 (yes with http) I receive an 404 error, powered by jetty.

Is there a way in jetty to detect if the received format is based on websockets format and if not(in our case http) to just close the socket connection and never return the 404 error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this yourself, but I don't think there's anything packaged with Jetty to do it.

If you're using the `WebSocketServlet`, then you should override the `service` method, to be something like

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
  if(!"WebSocket".equals(request.getHeader("Upgrade")))
  {
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request jettyRequest =  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getRequest(request);
     jettyRequest.getEndPoint().close();
     jettyRequest.setHandled(true);
  }
  else
  {
     super.service(request, response);
  }
}
```

If  you've rolled your own handler, then you should be able to work out how to adapt that code to your needs.

Comment: sorry to websockets will always have the Upgrade header in requests?

Comment: Yes, that's how Websockets work. They start as normal HTTP requests with a special header in them which causes the server to "upgrade" it to a websocket

Answer (score 0):

what Tim is suggesting is what the WebSocketServlet already does.
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-websocket/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketServlet.java

Just extend the WebSocketServlet and then use the various doGet, doPost, doPut methods for handling the HTTP requests.  Leave the service() method alone to do what it needs to.

Comment: The WebSocketServlet does nothing of the sort. Duoa wants to close non-websocket requests without providing an HTTP reponse. The WebSocketServlet treats normal HTTP request as well... ...normal HTTP requests, and provides 404 responses if nothing else handles them. It would be perfectly possible to override doGet, doPost, etc and call EndPoint.close() in each of them, but that's just an alternate (and IMO worse) implementation of my suggestion.